# A complex matrix which is hermitian positive definite and unitary is identity.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A complex matrix which is hermitian positive definite and unitary is identity.

Let $A$ be the given matrix. We have $ A^* =A$ , $AA^* = A^* A$ and $X^*AX > 0$, for non zero $X$.

How can we conclude from ere that $A$ is Identity?

Thank You.

Comment: Do you know a hermitian matrix is diagonalizable?

Answer (score 1):

Since $A$ is Hermitian, it is diagonalizable (this is the [spectral theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem)). Thus it suffices to prove that $1$ is the only eigenvalue of $A$. This follows from the fact that any eigenvalue of $A$ must be positive (because $A$ is positive definite) and have norm $1$ (because $A$ is unitary).